# How to use Javascript in a Node.js app to get external webpage info/webscraping?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, twitter

I am using the Twit API for Node.js, and have hosted my code on Heroku, which is where it is currently running from. I followed Daniel Shiffman's tutorials from : http://shiffman.net/a2z/twitter-bots/ and http://shiffman.net/a2z/bot-heroku/

I would like my bot to go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random and "get" the title. I would then post the title as a tweet. After some research, it seems that I would like to do something called webscraping. Let's say that the title of the wiki page resides in the `title` tag in the html file in the `head`. Does anyone know how I can access the url, and get the info I need? I'm not sure where to start. Search results on stackoverflow led me to outdated answers about using jquery and a yahoo api. A solution in javascript would be helpful, so that I know it is compatabile with heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Puppeteer, from Google to do it, look

[Github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

[Article](https://medium.com/@e_mad_ehsan/getting-started-with-puppeteer-and-chrome-headless-for-web-scrapping-6bf5979dee3e)

Comment: Thank you for this. It has worked very well. Exactly what I was looking for.